# While django admin is showing error

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a created a blog app. And while running admin url this error is comming

> ImportError at /admin/ No module named dbe.blog Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:   Django Version:    1.5.1 Exception Type:   ImportError
>   Exception Value:   No module named dbe.blog

In `admin.py` the code I have written given below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

Comment: Is `blog` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'polls',
 'article',
 'blog'
)

Comment: if you are using linux can you give us the output of this command? tree /path/to/your/project

Comment: sorry um using win 7 :(